# Odd construction, java converting static method to class

Tags: java, oop, interface, static-methods

I recently stumbled upon a piece of code which I couldn't explain with my understanding of java. I've created this small version of the same kind of construction:

```
public class StaticMethodClass {
    static void IDK(Integer i, String somethingElse) {
        System.out.println("It has been done");
    }

    public static void main(String... whatever) {
        Action.ITEM.doStuff();
    }
}

interface Func {
    void exec(Integer i, String somethingElse);
}

enum Action {
    ITEM(StaticMethodClass::IDK);

    private Func f;

    Action(Func f){
        this.f = f;
    }

    void doStuff() {
        this.f.exec(1, "huh");
    }
}
```

The part I can't wrap my head around it the way Action.ITEM is constructed, as it should get a class implementing the `Func` interface. Instead it is passed a method, which is somehow implicitly converts.

My question is how this works, and what rules apply here.

Comment: You should read about method references.

Comment: `StaticMethodClass::IDK` is a Reference to a function, that function has the same parameters and the same return type as the `Func.exec()` method thus this is a short form of implementing an interface with an already existing method

Comment: Refer Java docs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a relatively new construct, called [*method reference*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html). It was not available until Java 8.

> I can't wrap my head around it the way `Action.ITEM` is constructed, as it should get a class implementing the `Func` interface.

Method references provide a shortcut for creating such implementations: rather than you writing

```
ITEM((i, e) -> StaticMethodClass.IDK(i, e));
```

the compiler figures it out for you through the "shortcut" syntax, as long as the signature of `IDK` method is an exact match for the signature of `Func`'s `exec` method.

**Note:** Lambda version above is itself a shortcut for

```
ITEM(new Func() {
    @Override public exec(Integer i, String somethingElse) { 
        StaticMethodClass.IDK(i, somethingElse);
    }
});
```

so method reference is a shortcut for a shortcut.

Comment: I thought about giving an answer that would have looked  very much like this one. But unfortunately you covered all relevant aspects ... nothing left but upvoting.

Comment: Even your lambda "long version" is a java 8 shortcut for `new Func() {
   @Override
   public exec(Integer i, String somethingElse) {
    StaticMethodClass.IDK(i, somethingElse);
   }
  };`. I think your answer should include that, for exhaustivity.

Comment: @JeremyGrand Thank you very much for the comment!